# Is there any way to import parts of an ES module without side effects?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

When importing specific parts of a module, is it possible to import it *without* getting all the side effects that the module has?

Example:

- `Module_A.js` exports a class definition for a custom element (`CustomElement`), but also defines that element within the custom elements registry as a side effect
- `Module_B.js` imports `CustomElement` from `Module_A` so that it can extend it, but because `Module_A` already defines `CustomElement` in the registry, `Module_B` cannot define it's own element using that name.

Ideally, `Module_B` would be able to import `CustomElement` from `Module_A` without any of `Module_A`'s side effects running, allowing the specific parts that are desired to be used, without anything unexpected also running.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would module B create a class with different behaviour but register it under the same name?

Comment: @Bergi in this case it is because the I have a set of base elements that are primarily meant to be extended, to add minor customizations to each per project. The core intention of the element is the same though, so it doesn't really warrant a different tag name, in my opinion

Comment: OK, but if it is *meant* to be extended, then it should definitely not be registered itself. Also, are you sure that subclassing is the proper tool for customising this base element per project?

Comment: Primarily meant to be, but it is still capable of being used on it's own, and will be by default until it _is_ extended. I believe subclassing is the only way based on the types of customizations I need to do (certain methods are being replaced with slightly different behaviour). I think your answer is the best approach though... keeping the class definition and element registration separate let's me do what I need to do - avoiding registering the base element when it's not being used solo, even if it does unfortunately lead to a number of very small files needing to exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. All you can do is split up the modules to remove the side effects.

In your example,

- `CustomElement.js` would exports a class definition for a custom element (`CustomElement`)
- `Module_A.js` would import `CustomElement` and also define that element within the custom elements registry as a side effect
- `Module_B.js` would import `CustomElement` so that it can extend it, and define its own element using that name.